# Regex from 10000 to 1800000

Tags: regex, mongodb, optimization

My need is to check if the string is a number from 10000 included to 1800000 included.

I've came with the following regex :

```
^[1-9][0-9]{4}$|^[0-9]{6}$|^1[0-7][0-9]{5}$|^1800000$+
```

---

Is there a better or more optimized way of performing it ?

---

```js
const regex = /^[1-9][0-9]{4}$|^[0-9]{6}$|^1[0-7][0-9]{5}$|^1800000$/;

const mustFailTests = [
  '9999',
  '15',
  '00015',
  '-15000',
  '1800001',
  '9000000',
  '0',
  '',
];

const mustWorkTests = [
  '10000',
  '1800000',
  '200000',
  '25018',
  '778410',
  '1000000',
  '1205900',
];

const start = Date.now();

mustFailTests.forEach((x) => {
  const ret = regex.test(x);

  console.log(`${x} must fail : result ${ret}`);
});

console.log('--------------------------------');

mustWorkTests.forEach((x) => {
  const ret = regex.test(x);

  console.log(`${x} must succeed : result ${ret}`);
});

for (let i = 0; i < 500000; i += 1) {
  mustWorkTests.forEach(x => regex.test(x));
  mustFailTests.forEach(x => regex.test(x));
}

console.log(`It took ${Date.now() - start} ms`);
```

Comment: Is a leading zero a possibility? If so, could it be valid? eg `020000`

Comment: @CertainPerformance no there is not, it's a number that has been casted into a string and stored in the database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cleaner pattern might be to have an optional leading group containing 17 or lower, or any single digit, then follow that group by 5 more digits. Alternate with 1800000.

```js
const regex = /^(?:(?:1[0-7]|[0-9])?[0-9]{5}|1800000)$/;

const mustFailTests = [
  '9999',
  '15',
  '1800001',
  '9000000',
  '0',
  '',
];

const mustWorkTests = [
  '10000',
  '1800000',
  '200000',
  '25018',
  '778410',
  '1000000',
  '1205900',
];

const start = Date.now();

mustFailTests.forEach((x) => {
  const ret = regex.test(x);

  console.log(`${x} must fail : result ${ret}`);
});

console.log('--------------------------------');

mustWorkTests.forEach((x) => {
  const ret = regex.test(x);

  console.log(`${x} must succeed : result ${ret}`);
});

for (let i = 0; i < 500000; i += 1) {
  mustWorkTests.forEach(x => regex.test(x));
  mustFailTests.forEach(x => regex.test(x));
}

console.log(`It took ${Date.now() - start} ms`);
```

Answer (score 5):

why dont you convert that string to number and compare with the ones you need like this

```
const validate = (input) => 10000 <= +input && 1800000 >= +input
```

Comment: Because it's to integrate into a mongodb request (and yeah my tags are misleading, I'm going to change them)

Answer (score 2):

I agree that conversion to a number would probably be better, but if you need to use a regex:

The middle term of your current regex isn't right - it will currently match 000001. You can improve it by changing it to

> ^[1-9][0-9]{4,**5**}$|^1[0-7][0-9]{5}$|^1800000$

In general, you should have test cases that test unexpected input as well as expected inputs - leading 0s, numbers way too long, negatives, ect.

Comment: As I said to @duc mai the regex is for mongodb, so I can't turn the string into a number. It's a good regex improvement!